# What type has to be prefered between timestamp and datetime in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, types, timestamp

I am working with Pandas dataframes and often work with date columns. Then, I often have to convert them to a suitable type.

At this point I have 2 options:

- Timestamp or
- datetime

Both options allow me to access date attributes (like month, day) and have a bunch of similar functionalities. So I am wondering:

Is there an absolute prefered option or does it depend on the cases?

Comment: Whatever you want. Just make sure the format adheres to ISO 8601.

Comment: by datetime you mean pandas' (numpy) datetime64 dtype and timestamp = string?